# Solving Deadlock when acquiring Multiple Locks

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, deadlock

I have multiple threads T1, T2, T3 and T4 for example. T1 has resource A, T2 has resource B, T3 has resource A, B and C, T4 has resource B and C.

When T1 comes, it locks on A and do some work.

Then T2 comes, it locks on B and do some work.

Next is T3, it locks on C but is waiting on A (not yet B since A is not acquired yet).

Finally T4 here, it waits for B (not yet C since B is not acquired yet).

The pseudo code is like :

```
for all resources needed {  // in case of T3, they are A and B
    acquire lock on resource;  // acquiring lock one after one
}
```

Now if T2 finishes and releases the lock on B, T4 is waked up to lock on B. But it still needs to wait on C. So now T4 holds B and waits on C.

Deadlock occurs when T1 finishes and releases the lock on A, T3 is waked up to lock on A. But it still needs to wait on B. T3 now holds A and C and waits on B. Then I have T3 and T4 gone into an infinite wait.

To resolve this, my pseudo code changed to:

```
while not all resource locks obtained {  // in case of T3, they are A and B
    try to lock on resource;  // immediate return success or fail
    if fail, release all unsecured locks; // in case of T3, C is secured,
                                          // so only A and B may be released,
                                          // in case of T4, both B and C may be released
}
```

The changed code works but in my testing I could see T3 and T4 constantly checking on the locks and overall the program ran slower due to the while loop.

Then I made a small change to the code:

```
while not all resource locks obtained {
    try for 1 second to lock on resource;  // return after 1 second if fail
    if fail, release all unsecured locks;
}
```

The slight change made the check on locks less frequent and the program ran faster than before.

I don't like what I have at the moment because it seems not optimal and the effect is kind of random before reaching the desired result. Is there any better way to resolve the deadlock situation mentioned above or should I just settle on what I have now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preventing deadlocks is simple:

1. Never escalate a lock, such as escalating a read lock into a write lock
2. **Always acquire locks in the same order**

You're not doing the second.  You're just randomly trying to acquire locks - of course that's inefficient.

Comment: @EJP It's not *wrong*, it's just, umm, deliberately understated. :-)

Comment: A technique with a throughput of zero is neither efficient nor inefficient: it is wrong. If you're trying to make a sort of a joke, you haven't succeeded.

Comment: @EJP *A technique with a throughput of zero is neither efficient nor inefficient: it is wrong.*  Per the OP's comment: "The slight change made the check on locks less frequent and the program ran faster than before." Evidently throughput is not zero.  In fact, you could say that the change the OP was commenting on made his code more *efficient*, and it's quite likely a better locking scheme would make it even more *efficient*.  If you were trying to make a point...

Comment: I could have made the program single thread to avoid using locks at all...

Comment: @AndrewHenle The throughput of a deadlocked application is zero. If it wasn't zero, he doesn't have a deadlock and the premiss of the question is wrong. It wouldn't be the first time. A lot of people mistakenly use 'deadlock' to mean just 'lock'.

Comment: @EJP Per the question: ***Deadlock occurs** ... To resolve this ... a small change to the code ... made the check on locks less frequent **and the program ran faster than before.***  Again: ***the program ran faster than before***  Clearly, the question is about deadlocks, and it's explicitly about "solving" them. Care to comment on the effect on *efficiency* of ***the program ran faster than before***?  This is not just a simple question about avoiding deadlocks. It also presented a "try-and-hope" solution that one could say is quite **inefficient**. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_holes

Answer (score 1):

The solution to any genuine deadlock is to always acquire the locks in the same order. No sleeps or retries required.

Comment: @user1589188, Some people _do_ write code in which two or more threads are so tightly coupled by shared data structures and their attendant locks that they are unable to work any faster than (or even as fast _as_) a single threaded program could do.  It is up to the designer of the program to break that tight coupling---to find ways to let the threads go off and work independently of each other as far as that is possible.

Comment: @user1589188 No it isn't: for example, not every thread may acquire every lock, but in any case it is the only way to avoid deadlock, so there is nothing valid to compare it with.

Comment: @EJP my last pseudo code did resolve my deadlock situation, although inefficient, so my question is about any better way that sits between single threaded and my periodic checking.